# Configuring ssl on aws ec2 with elastic load balancer service unavailable?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

i have setup bitnami wordpress on my ubuntu 64 bit server and now want to add ssl provided by amazon. i have followed following [tutorial](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/how-to/configure-elb-ssl-aws/) by bitnami

i am on last step:

```
/opt/bitnami/apps/APPNAME/conf/httpd-prefix.conf
```

but when i enter this command in ssh . it says permission denied.

and wen i open my web it says : service temporary unavailable " 
but i can visit my web with public ip of instance its working.

Answer (score 0):

You don't enter the file into ssh. You edit the file with a text editor such as "nano" or "vi". Then follow the instructions.

vi opt/bitnami/apps/APPNAME/conf/httpd-prefix.conf